# RecyclerView item click and open another recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

enter image description hereI have almost 250 patent item which i want to show in a parent recyclerview. After item click of parent recyclerview it will show over hundreds of data under each parent item in another recycler view. How can i do it like this picture.

[image]

Comment: Please add the image its not showing in here  @Md

Comment: Yah. I already add

Comment: You need to show in another screen or you want to show this in single screen as shown in the picture?

Comment: i want to show in Another screen

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way. Create an interface:

```
interface AdapterContract{
  fun onListItemClick(id: String) //whatever the parameter is
}
```

When you instantiate the Adapter in your `Fragment1`, you can implement this interface:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment(), AdapterContract{
  ...
  //when instantiating the adapter:
  private val adapter: MyAdapter by lazy{
      MyAdapter(this //for the interface)
  }
  //override the method of Adapter contract
}
```

Your adapters constructor should look like this: `MyAdapter(adapterContract: AdapterContract) : ListAdapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(Diff_Util_SOME_OBJECT)`

Than in the adapters ViewHolder:

```
itemHolder?.setOnClickListener{
 adapterContract.onListItemClick(someId)
}
```

Now in your override method in `Fragment1`:

```
override method onListItemClick(id: String){
  //pass this id to the next opening fragment (like Bundles or navargs)
 //init `Fragment2` which is going to have all items, that belong to `Fragment1` selected item
}
```

Load the data :)

I hope you are using a database or something. Should work with hard coded data structures as well, but just to be safe :).

Comment: Have you any tutorial like this?

Comment: I just made it.

Comment: Actually i am new in Android development. Where can i get this??

Comment: I'm talking about the answer. It's already all the steps you need.

Comment: Actually i need the full process. Cause i am new in android development. It will be helpful for me....

Comment: oh, sorry I can't remember any. But search for something like: "How to handle RecyclerView item click and open a new list android". Good luck